# Hilt : Field Inject with Parameters like Koin

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, koin

I am migrating Koin to Hilt so its quite easy but i am stuck in one point that how can I pass parameters in Field Injection like Koin,
In koin I am able to pass parameter in field injection like below code

```
  private val socket: Socket by inject { parametersOf(roomId) }
```

But I don't know how can i achieve this thing in Hilt! If anyone know that it would be very helpful for me.
Basic I want to pass some dynamic value in some class so how can I use that

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `@AssistedInject` for your class and `@Assisted` for the id parameter.

```
class MyClass @AssistedInject constructor(
  @Assisted private val id: Long
)
```

Then create `@AssistedFactory` that will create the instance of MyClass

```
@AssistedFactory
  interface MyClassFactory {
    fun create(roomId : Long): MyClass
  }
```

Then inject the factory where you need it and use it lazily:

```
@Inject 
late init var myFactory : MyClassFactory

private val myClass by lazy { myFactory.create(roomId) }
```

Read: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html

Comment: Thanks, @Nikola for your answer but you know Socket class is from dependencies so I need to create a separate class for that?